# Script to draw image

Tags: php, javascript, image, image-processing

I am looking for a PHP script that will allow me to draw an image with my mouse and save it as an image.  If you know of any please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you *do* feel like reinventing a few wheels :-)

Make a Javascript snippet that lets you draw. This can of course be as advanced or simple as you wish, for example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),   
    pos = false;

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

$(canvas).bind("mousedown", function(evt) {
    pos = {x: evt.layerX, y: evt.layerY};
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
});

$(canvas).bind("mousemove", function(evt) {
    if(!pos) return; // You may not want to do this on every mousemove.
    pos = {x: evt.layerX, y: evt.layerY};
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    ctx.stroke();
});

$(canvas).bind("mouseup", function(evt) {
    if(!pos) return;
    ctx.closePath();
    pos = false;
});
```

Also add a button that sends the image data to your PHP script:

```
$('#btn').bind("click", function(evt) { 
    $.post('saveImage.php', {image : canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')});
});
```

In your saveImage.php script on the server, decode the data and write it to a file.

```
$imgData = $_POST["image"]; // Probably a good idea to sanitize the input!
$imgData = str_replace(" ", "+", $imgData);
$imgData = substr($imgData, strpos($imgData, ","));

$file = fopen('myImage.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, base64_decode($imgData));
fclose($file);
```

Should do the trick :-) I'm using jQuery for the JS bits here, that's of course not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is executed server-side, whereas interaction with the mouse is carried out client-side. You would need to use an in-browser technology like JavaScript or Flash to capture the mouse movements and generate bitmap data first.

Comment: Thank you I have already figured that out, but being out of time for the moment i dont want to re invent the wheel if it has been invented before me... I am looking for a script that can do this